# Restricting the flutter app's orientation

Tags: flutter, android-orientation

How can I restrict the app orientation on flutter?

`SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])`

I've tried this code but it doesn't work out.

Comment: Can you show the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried works, actually. However, it is not *forcing* the orientation, it is merely *preferring* it. That means, for example, that if you try to set your orientation to landscape with

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscape])
```

Flutter will not rotate the orientation, but if you rotate your device from portrait to landscape, then the app orientation will be locked to landscape.

If you want Flutter to programatically rotate the orientation, *forcing* it instead of *preferring* it, consider using the [auto_orientation package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_orientation).

After importing the package you can use `AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();` to lock the orientation to landscape.

Answer (score 1):

For android, you can define the orientation in your AndroidManifest.xml using the `android:screenOrientation` property

```xml
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: I Need solution for flutter

Comment: @MohamedNusky this works for flutter. You open the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file in your flutter project and add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the `<activity` tag.

Answer (score 0):

King Elisha's answer works well for Android. If you are facing the same issue on IOS, here is a solution:

- Go to your "ios/Runner/Info.plist" file
- Find the key "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" or create it if you somehow don't have it.
- Set the key value as "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait"

The final output should look like this:

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
```

This can be done by the selection on XCode Runner/General/Deployment Info/iPhone Orientation as well.

I hope my first answer will be useful to someone :)